# Node: How to read file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read a file and return is as a response to `GET` request

This is what I am doing

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return 'some issue on reading file';
        }
        var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'utf8');
        console.log(buffer.toString());
        response.send(buffer.toString());
    });
});
```

`index.html` is

```
hello world!
```

When I load page `localhost:5000`, the page spins and nothing happens, what is I am doing incorrect here

I am newbie to Node.

Comment: What does the rest of you app / server configuration look like? Are you seeing any console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the *synchronous* version of the [`readFile` method](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback). If that's what you intended, don't pass it a callback. It returns a string (if you pass an encoding):

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.send(fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf8'));
});
```

Alternatively (and generally more appropriately) you can use the asynchronous method (and get rid of the encoding, since you appear to be expecting a `Buffer`):

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
        // In here, `data` is a string containing the contents of the file
    });
});
```